# Scroll horizontally and don't drop to the next line

Tags: html, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to get a list that scrolls horizontally instead of dropping on to the next line. I have something like the following but can only see the first items before it drops to the next line. I want this to continue on one line and just scroll horizontally.

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100' alt="">
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100' alt="">
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100' alt="">
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100' alt="">
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100' alt="">
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100' alt="">
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100' alt="">
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100' alt="">
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100' alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Due to all the extra elements on the page I had to do some tweaks like wrapping everything in the div inside another span and using positioning on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), `display: flex`, will align horizontally your content (use `flex-direction: column` for vertical).

```css
div{
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  display: flex;
}

div img {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<h1> Before </h1>
<div>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
</div>
<h1> After </h1>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, I tried this as well but the whole page scrolls sideways to allow for it the same as I said in the comment for the white-space answer

Comment: As long as you don't have any content inside your `div` the whole page should not scroll ? Could you show us your whole html ?

Comment: There's way too much going on to show everything most of the HTML is being generated from DB's with PHP. Basically this list is a list of products each product is a span with an image two paragraphs and a button. And there's already some flex going on with the parent elements

Answer (score 6):

This is the easiest and correct way to do this. The other methods do work but the intended way to do is like so:

```css
div.scrollable{
  width:500px;
  height:130px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, I tried this but the whole page scrolls sideways to allow for it. As in the page header etc scroll off the page to the left as I scroll right to look at the list

Comment: @PaddyHallihan hi, can you explain your problem more in detail? I dont quite get what you mean with your comment above. Please note: if you copy my code exactly as it is it won't work. you will need to add a class to your div so that not every div on your page gets updated with the properties. I modified my answer so you can see how it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```css
.main{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:500px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  max-height:120px;
}

.main img {
   
margin: 5px;

}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I did not downvote, but your answer seems to be overcomplicated. Maybe that's the reason. Check out my answer above for a much cleaner approach

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the advice. I’ll be sure to keep my code as simple as possible in the future :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your code is working perfectly fine and is probably also a good way to go. The above solution would just be the intended way to achieve the demanded result and is therefore better. I still don't get why someone would downvote your post though.

Comment: I believe the reason was simply, there's 2 (main) ways of doing this; using `display: flex;` like the first answer did or using `overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;`... but you decided to do both... - You wasted a couple lines of code. Kinda like prepending `all: unset;` to every css selector (BTW - Yes, I'm aware that this question is a year old)